# Keyboard and mouse not working after boot

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, dpkg

My keyboard and mouse are not working at all, ubuntu16.04 boots and displays the desktop but I can't use the keyboard nor the mouse.

EDIT: The keyboard works fine in recovery mode (grub)

Any idea ?

Thanks

ThinkPad t450

Comment: Did you install device drivers ?

Comment: I don't know. Can I do that without keyboard or maybe in grub recovery mode ?